# How to display Subtraction of two fields and display as a column in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I am using SQL server data base. I need to display total no of nights based on checkindate and checkout date. i am new in Power BI.

I tried by `quick measure` but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in different ways - calculate the duration in the database, add custom column in M or column in DAX.

In SQL Server use select query like this:

```
select checkindate, checkoutdate, datediff(day, checkindate, checkoutdate) as duration from table
```

In M (Power Query) - click `Edit queries` to open Power Query editor and then `Add Column` -> `Custom column`:

[image]

```
Duration.Days(Duration.From([checkoutdate]-[checkindate]))
```

[image]

In DAX - right click your table and select `New column`:

[image]

```
Duration_DAX = DATEDIFF('Table'[checkoutdate]; 'Table'[checkindate]; DAY)
```

[image]

Note, that depending on your settings, you may have to use comma (,) instead of semicolon (;) in the DAX expression above.